# Confirmation of redundant term in equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification

Hi I have a quick simple question from a proof I am working through. I just want confirmation. Are the $[x,y]$ outside of the weak closure redundant in equation (2) of the attachment, since "$$\text{w-cl}\big(\bigcap_{z \in K \cap [x,y]}T_{1}\big)(z)\cap [x,y] = \text{w-cl}\big( \bigcap_{z \in K \cap [x,y]}T_{1}(z)\big)$$"? It seems like it is redundant since it looks like $$\bigcap_{z \in K \cap [x,y]} T_{1}(z) : K \cap [x,y] \rightarrow K \cap [x,y]$$

See the description of the mappings and equations (2) from Remark 2 below. $K \subset X$, where $X$ is a Banach space.

[image]

Comment: Where is this extract taken from?

Comment: @Dansmith It is taken from [the paper](http://webpages.csus.edu/~domokos/pseu1.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

What's $T(x)$? You need to define it in order to define $T_1,T_2$. But right it away it seems like the $[x,y]$ are going to be necessary: just because $z\in [x,y]$, it doesn't mean that any $z'\in K$ which satisfies $\langle T(z'),y-z'\rangle\geq 0$ will also need to belong to the line segment $z'\in [x,y]$.

Comment: I agree, that straight off it doesn't seem like you can discard it. Take a look at [the paper](http://webpages.csus.edu/~domokos/pseu1.pdf), from the full proof it seems like you can discard it.